# Jekyll compare strings

Tags: html, jekyll

I have my current `page.url` in jekyll:

```
/chorals/2018/01/12/post.html
```

I would like to extract the word `chorals` alone so that I can compare it. What I am doing is:

```
{% assign postcategory = page.url | split:"/" | split:" " %}
```

Then I do:

```
{% if postcategory == "&quot;chorals&quot;&#44;" %}
```

The html codes are equivalent to:

```
&quot; = "
&#44; = ,
```

I.e. I am comparing `postcategory` with `"chorals",`

But this if check never works, any ideas please?

Comment: If `postcategory` equals `"chorals",` and you compare it with `&quot;chorals&quot;&#44;` it's expected to not be equal, those are different strings.

Comment: Jekyll converts html codes to the corresponding character values. i.e. if I print `"&quot;chorals&quot;&#44;"`, it shows `"chorals",`. How do you suggest a string comparison then? There is no escape character in Jekyll.

Comment: `{% if postcategory == '"chorals",' %}` ?

Comment: AWESOME! This worked, thank you so much!